# Adding annotation pin in mapview depending on cell chosen

Tags: xcode, uitableview, annotations, mapkit

I have Table View controller, then it has subclass DetailViewController, which content changes depending on cell chosen, but when move on, and from my DetailViewController go to MapView, I try to use same method I used to get text on DetailViewController, but it dont works, no matter what I do. Im stuck with it more like 3 week now:(

```
 - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

{
         if (!self.detailViewController) {
        self.detailViewController = [[DetailViewController alloc]            initWithNibName:@"DetailViewController" bundle:nil];

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:self.detailViewController animated:YES];
[self.detailViewController changeProductText:[teksti objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
[self.detailViewController changeProductText1:[adrese objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
[self.detailViewController changeProductText2:[laimigastunda objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
[self.detailViewController changeImage:[imageChange objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];



}
```

}
No matter what I change here, it dont work.

Comment: The way the code is written, the detail view only gets pushed if it's nil (perhaps the first time you select a row).  Afterwards, nothing is done.  Is that by design?  Also, please explain in more detail what "it doesn't work" means (eg. doesn't push, detail view is empty, crash, compiler warning, other).  Does the detail view's viewDidLoad execute?  Add breakpoints and NSLogs.  Step through the code in the debugger.

Comment: DetailViewController works perfect, but problem come's when I navigate from DetailViewController to MapController, and try to use same method as i did to DetailViewController, to get loaded different coordinates to MapController, there isn't code above for it because it dont work. Before i tried this method[self.mapController cord:[coordChange objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];, it was added just after [self.detailViewController changeImage:[imageChange objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

Comment: Please post the code that didn't work into the question.  So the DetailViewController has a table view?  Then in the DetailViewController's didSelectRowAtIndexPath method, you have this code?  Why would you be pushing and setting detailViewController inside itself?  Perhaps I don't understand the problem.

Comment: No, DeatailViewController.h has 4 labels and 1 picture view which change depending on row selected at TableViewController.h. Also my DetailViewController has button called map on navigation bar, who pushes MapController.h. My goal is to get MapController.h annotations change same as DetailViewControllers.h labels and pictures change,when table row selected.

Comment: What code do you use to go to mapView? Here you give code only to show detailview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks from the code you are showing that you are not giving a data object to your detailViewController, but rather set directly the values.

This is not the way to do it and probably the reason why you are having issues. You need to grasp the concept of MVC and go back to it.

At least you should 
1. build a dictionary in first view with keys @"teksti", @"adrese", @"longitude", @latitude". 
2. Create a property in DetailViewController to hold the dictionary. 
3. update the values displayed when displaying the DetailViewController

So that when you press the map button, you can then push a view containing a mapView and set the map to the latitude and longitude that you have.

So it would do:

```
  NSDictionary *dict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:[teksti objectAtIndex:indexPath.row], @"teksti", [adrese objectAtIndex:indexPath.row], @"adrese", [latitude objectAtIndex:indexPath.row], @"latitude", [longitudes objectAtIndex:indexPath.row], @"longitude", nil];
  [detailViewController setDict:dict];
```

and in the DetailViewController.m:

```
  - (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
  [self changeProductText:[dict objectForKey:@"teksti"]];
  .... And so on
  }
```

Your code will be useful to provide you with more details directions.